# How do I avoid the HTML I enter is altered?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I use drupal 8.4.3 with ckeditor 4.7.2 (apparently)

When I press the "source" button, I want to be able to write whatever source I want, in just one line if I want to, I don't want the ckeditor to touch my source code AT ALL.

How is that possible? I think I have used 3 hours googling, without making it work completely.

I want to be able to write "`<br><br>`" without it turning by code into:

```
<br /> (-- LINE BREAK)
<br />
```

I don't want it to touch it!!! it should just be `<br><br>` (without the closing /)

when I write into the source, ckeditor shouldn't touch it! How is that possible?

Comment: disable ckeditor?

Comment: What happens when you edit twice the same node? Do you see that `<br>` is changed in `<br />`, or is that only output when the node is rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not just CKeditor altering your HTML. You should look into the configuration of your input formats at `/admin/config/content/formats`. There is documentation on https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/filter/overview, although it's not very detailed.

An input format applies one or more text filters to your input. Common filters are the *HTML Filter*, that allows only a limited number of HTML tags, and the *Line Break Converter*, which turns line ends into `<br>` or `<p>` tags. You can configure your input format, or create a new one, without any filters.

If I recall correctly, even if you don't have any text filters configured, Drupal may still strip some HTML tags that are considered particularly dangerous, like the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I tried deleting all filters but still it decides to use it's won "reformat" issue.

Comment: Without other information, this answer is the most complete, also because the OP doesn't say if the change happens when rendering the node, or the node content is changed when saving it. I would add that a module could alter what saved for a node, or what rendering a node.

Comment: It's OK. I still cannot fathom  why there is not (or maybe there is but I don't know about it) an option in CKEDITOR called something like "DO NOT TOUCH MY HTML AT ALL". I want my <br> tags to be on one line only, and without the closing / (making it <br />), if that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /admin/config/content/formats, create new text format without ckeditor:
[image]

Comment: There are input filters that alter what entered. Excluding the editor doesn't alter the input filters used from the input format.

Comment: Well it's ok, but does not really resolve the issue, because if there are 2 persons editing the same node, one with ckeditor, and one without, then ckeditor will use it's almighty power and override everything.

Comment: The closest I came to: `function hook_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {
foreach ($settings['editor']['formats'] as $name => $value) {
 $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['autoParagraph'] = false;
 $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['fillEmptyBlocks'] = false;
 $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['ignoreEmptyParagraph'] = false;
 $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['scayt_autoStartup'] = false;
 $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['removePlugins'] = 'htmldataprocessor';
 }
}`

Comment: @RafA. If one of two users is not using CKEditor, then it's not CKEditor that is causing the issue.